# Parallelize a for loop in Spyder (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-3.5, python-multiprocessing, spyder

I'm trying to parallelize a for loop in python 3.5
So I turned everything that happened inside the for loop into one function (functionreplacingloop) and then used multiprocessing.pool to map the function for the different inputs (listofinputs) that I was previously looping through:

```
p = Pool(5)
answers = p.map(functionreplacingloop, listofinputs)
```

And then the console gets stuck. Even if I click 'stop the current command' it's still stuck and I have to quit the console.

I tried the same thing with joblib.parallel and got the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried including debugging output via `print()` in the function you are running?

Comment: Could you try to use `ipyparallel` instead? That should work without problems in Spyder.